# How to repeat 1000 times this random walk simulation in R?

Tags: r, time-series, sampling, random-walk

I'm simulating a one-dimensional and symmetric random walk procedure:

```
y[t] = y[t-1] + epsilon[t]
```

where white noise is denoted by `epsilon[t] ~ N(0,1)` in time period `t`. There is no drift in this procedure.

Also, RW is symmetric, because `Pr(y[i] = +1) = Pr(y[i] = -1) = 0.5`.

Here's my code in R:

```
set.seed(1)
t=1000
epsilon=sample(c(-1,1), t, replace = 1)

y<-c()
y[1]<-0
for (i in 2:t) {
  y[i]<-y[i-1]+epsilon[i]
}
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(1:t, y, type="l", main="Random walk")
outcomes <- sapply(1:1000, function(i) cumsum(y[i]))
hist(outcomes)
```

I would like to simulate 1000 different `y[i,t]` series (`i=1,...,1000; t=1,...,1000`). (After that, I will check the probability of getting back to the origin (`y[1]=0`) at `t=3`, `t=5` and `t=10`.)

Which function would allow me to do this kind of repetition with `y[t]` random walk time-series?

Comment: I agree with @Tim - but I think it's a good question to ask on stack overflow. Can we transfer the question to there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `y[t] = y[0] + sum epsilon[i]`, where the `sum` is taken from `i=1` to `i=t`, the sequence `y[t]` can be computed at once, using for instance R `cumsum` function. Repeating the series T=10³ times is then straightforward:

```
N=T=1e3
y=t(apply(matrix(sample(c(-1,1),N*T,rep=TRUE),ncol=T),1,cumsum))
```

since each row of `y` is then a simulated random walk series.